# Как оптимизировать код [python]?

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Решаю задание: "Даны две строки X и Y. Напишите программу, которая посчитает, сколько подстрок строки Y являются анаграммами строки X". У меня есть код, он работает, но на 10 тесте он выдаёт ошибку, потому что тратится слишком много времени. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать код.

```
x = str(input())
y = str(input())

len_x = len(x)

list_x = list(x)
list_x.sort()

count = 0
for i in range(len(y)):
    slice_y = list(y[i:i + len_x])
    slice_y.sort()
    if slice_y == list_x:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте словарик, содержащий символы `X` и их счётчики (`dct = {'a':2; 'l':1; 'v':1}` для `'lava'`)

Заводите переменную `nonmatch_cnt = len(dct)`

Для первых `len(x)` символов из `Y` делаете вот что - если символ есть в словаре, отнимаете от счётчика 1. Если данный счётчик становится равным нулю - отнимаете единицу от `nonmatch_cnt`, а если из нуля становится ненулевым - добавляете единицу к `nonmatch_cnt`

Проходите в цикле окном длиной `len(x)` по длине строки `Y`, на каждом шаге обрабатывая уходящий из окна символ (первый) и входящий (новый), как описано выше (для уходящего символа, имеющегося в словаре, к соотв. счетчику единицу прибавляем)

В моменты, когда `nonmatch_cnt` равен нулю - в окне находится анаграмма строки `X` (при этом количество каждого символа в окне равно количеству  появлений соотв. символа в `X`)

Время работы линейное `O(len(Y))`

```
x:lava   y:aavalal
4 шага
dct                          nonmatch_cnt    
{'a':-1; 'l':1; 'v':0}        2
{'a':0; 'l':0; 'v':0}         0   *
{'a':0; 'l':0; 'v':0}         0   *
{'a':0; 'l':-1; 'v':1}        2
```

Comment: @yngdev Ну что, разобрались?